# Loading div object from DoM. Convert to Text File. Then reload div object back when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a co worker who asked me for help but I wasn't able to. Essentially he has created a page with pure java script that has a div element and child div elements. Each one of those child div elements have a form. He wants to be able to save all that hierarchical data in a text file whether or not it is in json / html in which he can load it later on without having to process it manually again. That way the next time the person loads the page, they are greeted with all the same information and div elements.

So essentially when you load the page again, you are able to simply dump the json / html into the DoM and it will automagically work. He's been on it for 2 days now, I thought I would ask you guys for some help or at least lead me on the right path.

Comment: Serializing DOM is easy. Saving and loading files too, but requires user interaction each time. Look up on SO (or tell your coworker to), you'll find all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Doing so would take three steps:

- Get all the form data values from the DOM (a simple matter of knowing how to access HTML forms and putting them into an object)
- Save the form data object into localStorage or on server (saving on the server would only work if you save some identifying information about the user, like if they are logged in, or their IP address)
- On form load, check for saved data (on localStorage or server) and load it into the forms.

You can get the data of all forms into a JSON object like so:

```
function getAllFormsData(){

   var formsData = {}

   for(var i=0;i<document.forms.length;i++){

       var form = document.forms[i],
           name = document.forms[i].name;
       formsData[name] = {}

       for(var j=0;j<form.elements.length;j++){
           var element = form.elements[j];
           if(element.type=="submit") continue;
           formsData[name][element.name] = element.value;
       }
    }
    return formsData;
}
```

so `formsData` is a JSON object that contains properties for each form (by its name, but you can use ID if you prefer) on the page, and the value of each of those properties is an object containing the name and value of each input element (unless it's a `submit` type element).

Saving the data can be triggered either by the user clicking a "Save" Button on the page, or by using the `window.onunload` event. (If you are using localStorage, you can also set the saving function inside a `setInterval` that triggers every 30 seconds or whatever.)

localStorage is pretty straightforward ([with a really easy API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)), but only allows string values. If you want to load a whole object into it instead of having to loop through and save each value, you can use a library. I have found [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) to be very useful and straightforward, and it serializes data for you so you don't need to mess with `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify`.

So, using the library, the save function would boil down to something as simple as:

```
function saveAllFormsData(){
    var data = getAllFormsData();
    for(var formName in data)
        store.set(formName, data[formName]);
}
```

And on load, you can call this function:

```
function restoreAllFormsData(){

    var forms = document.forms;
    for(var i=0;i<forms.length;i++){
        var form = forms[i];
        if(store.get(form.name)){
                for(var j=0;j<form.elements.length;j++){
                    var element = form.elements[j];
                    if(element.type=="submit")
                        continue;
                    element.value = store.get(form.name)[element.name];
                }               
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into [HTML5 local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). This will allow you to save form data on the client, which can be used for repopulation when necessary.

Alternatively, you could also set a cookie on the client. However, this method has drawbacks that are discussed in the aforementioned document.

Either approach will likely require you to [stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) any HTML before storage, due to the key:value nature of these data storage methods.